# capture images every n second by using open cv with android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am searching for any code or any thing can help me for capture images every n second by using android with open cv and **save** all images in SD card.

I have tried this code but not working ..

1. set small picture size:

   ```
   List<Camera.Size> list = param.getSupportedPictureSizes();
   size = list.get(list.size() - 1);//or list.size() - 2,-3,-4
   param.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
   ```
2. do every

   ```
   camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
   ```

in a thread.

```
new Thread(){};
```

Comment: This method is only valid when preview is active. Have you called startPreview()?

Comment: yes i made .. but not working ..

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste *the full code*? I can't find out the problem with so little code.

You can try to print a log in the `pictureCallback`. Then you can see whether the log is printed. If so, there is wrong with saving photos. Otherwise, there is wrong with starting camera.

Comment: sorry sir, i do not understand , all i need already clear project to do it